# How can I divide two table fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is in my model:

```
before_save :set_pay_this


  def set_pay_this
    self.pay_this = "#{self.amount} / #{self.divisor}"
  end

end
```

But what gets saved as "pay this" is the "amount" entry, so no division is being done. Is it my syntax or what else should I post to ask my question properly?

Comment: You're creating a string using string interpolation. If you want to do math, do math.

Comment: Fell for that one a few times myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"#{self.amount} / #{self.divisor}"` is a string.  If amount was 5 and divisor was 2 you'd end up with `"5 / 2"` the string, not the mathematical equation.  You want this:

```
self.pay_this = self.amount / self.divisor
```

Or maybe this if you care about the cents and amount and divisor are integers.

```
self.pay_this = self.amount.to_f / self.divisor
```